# Running an animation after a set time using animate.css

Tags: jquery, css, animation

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/GunhR/)

You can see from the example that I am trying to animate the box coming down from the top, and then after a few seconds it will pulse. I am using [animate.css](http://daneden.me/animate/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="animated bounceInDown box" id="icon1">This is a test</div>
```

**JS**

```
setInterval(function() {
    console.log('Running animation');
    $('#icon1').addClass('animated pulse');
}, 4000);
```

If you take away the bounceInDown it works, but why won't both work together?

To make things more complicated, adding animations that remove the element work, [like in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jWNSP/).

It seems I cannot use any of the below animations in the timer, does anyone know why? Or is this a bug?

- flash
- bounce
- shake
- tada
- swing
- wobble
- pulse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can not apply more than one class animation at the same time.

Removing the `bounceInDown` before applying the new class works well:

```
$('#icon1').removeClass('bounceInDown').addClass('pulse');
```

Living example: http://jsfiddle.net/GunhR/2/

Comment: @Adam it was Kyra, who knows what motivated him to do it :) Your welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('Running animation');
    $('#icon1').removeClass('bounceInDown');
    $('#icon1').addClass('pulse');
}, 4000);
```

Comment: Can I ask why did you answer exactly the same as I did?

Comment: @Alvaro yeah, didn't reload the answers, should've paid more attention.